# How can I search the OMDB Api for titles that contain the search term?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am searching the OMDB API for movies and using the onChange method to search as users type. I want the results to be movies that contain words like the search term and not only the exact search term. For example, typing "ram" should include Rambo, Rambo 2, Hey Ram and more, but Ram is displaying only movies that match "Ram" exactly.

Here's the code block, using React:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SearchandResult = () =>{

    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
    const [searchResult, setSearchResult] = useState([]);
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    const typedChange = (e) => {
        setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
        setIsReady(true)
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        if (isReady) {
            if (searchTerm.length >= 3) {
                axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchTerm}&apikey=xxxxx`)
                    .then(res=> setSearchResult(res.data.Search))
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
            else if (searchTerm.length === 0 || searchTerm.length < 3) {
                setSearchResult([]);
            }
        }
    }, [isReady, searchTerm])


    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <input type="search" value = { searchTerm } onChange = { typedChange } />
            </form>
            <div>
                {
                    searchResult.length > 0 && searchResult.map( ( result, i ) => 
                    <p key={i}>
                        {result.Title} {result.Year}
                    </p>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SearchandResult;
```

Comment: It seems to not have been documented, but according to [this issue](https://github.com/omdbapi/OMDb-API/issues/108) it supports wildcard search: `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchTerm}*`

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the edit and response. I found a fix here: https://www.florin-pop.com/blog/2019/02/react-movie-search-app/ . I will be sure to post the solution here later today. Thanks once again